# Keycloak facade service

Tags: spring-boot, security, architecture, microservices, keycloak

I'm working on a system where I would like to implement a facade service that does some user-related stuff in it and also communicates with the Keycloak server via its rest API. Keycloak has its own database and other services their own as well.

So the facade service should be registered in Keycloak configuration as a *public client* for the client (mobile app), but the facade to Keycloak should be as a *service account*, as I don't want to add the role that can query users to the client's user.

The flow should go like this:

Mobile app calls the backend service to retrieve some data (it is registered as keycloak public client) and the backend service calls Keycloak via rest template (but with confidential client configuration as a service account ) to retrieve user info, aggregate the results, do some business related stuff , agregate the results and return them to the mobile app

Is something like doable?

Comment: My understanding is that one client with public access type is created for a mobile app. Another client with a confidential access type is created for a backend service. Then for backend client, you will be able to enable Service Account and set proper Service Account Roles (as Service Account is enabled for confidential access-type only).

Comment: Well maybe it is a little confusing, so in the mobile app, one should be able to authenticate via username/password, and it receives an access-token, with that token it can call that backend for some data, but in the same time the backend should be able to call Keycloaks API and for that, we need clientId and clientSecret for authentication and not the access-token from the mobile app.

Comment: clientId and client secret should be stored somewhere in environment variables so backend service can use them for connecting to Keycloak.